# How to download an artifact from MLFlow using REST?

Tags: rest, databricks, mlflow

I see the Python API:
`download_artifacts(run_id: str, path: str, dst_path: Optional[str] = None) → str` ([here](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.tracking.html#mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient.download_artifacts)), but I can't find the equivalent in REST.